# Сохранение игры unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Прошу помочь, сейчас занимаюсь над сохранением игры и возникла проблема. Если вкратце, у меня аркада под андроид, в каждом уровне которой можно заработать типо коинов, а перед началом каждого уровня у меня есть панель с общим количеством этих самых коинов. Вот сбилдил я игру на андроид и получилось, что каждый раз когда я выхожу из игра и захожу заново, эти коины не сохраняются и сбрасываются до нуля. То же самое и с уровнями, у меня уровни random.range определяются , и каждый раз как я перезахожу сбрасывается на первый уровень, но это не так критично, как с монетками.(Я знаю про playerprefs но не понимаю как его использовать в моем случае)
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в Unity есть инструмент PlayerPrefs.
Для записи( обновляй префс по ключу "coins" каждый раз, когда игрок берёт монетку)

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins",_coins);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Метод GetInt используй для чтения. В твоём случае верно будет сделать так:

```
_coinsCounter.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins");
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего использовать что то надёжнее чем `PlayerPrefs` так как он сохраняет на устройстве не защищенные данные которые пользователь сможет изменить без особых проблем, грубо говоря взломать, но для первого опыта можно взять его.

Для создания `PlayerPrefs` необходимо понимать термин **ключ** ***(key)*** - это `string` наименование, которое хранить в себе на устройстве переданное значение определенного типа,`PlayerPrefs` позволяет сохранять значения трёх типов: `Int`, `String`, `Float`.

**Его основные методы:**

`PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string keyName, int value);` // Передает значение **value** в ключ **keyName**

`PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string keyName);` // Возвращает значение из ключа **keyName**

`PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(string keyName, float value);` // Передает значение **value** в ключ **keyName**

`PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(string keyName);` // Возвращает значение из ключа **keyName**

`PlayerPrefs.SetString(string keyName, string value);` // Передает значение **value** в ключ **keyName**

`PlayerPrefs.GetString(string keyName);` // Возвращает значение из ключа **keyName**

`PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(string keyName);` // Удаляет полностью ключ.

`PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();` // Удаляет все ключи

`PlayerPrefs.HasKey(string keyName);` // Возвращает `true` если ключ существует, `false` если ключа нет

`PlayerPrefs.Save();` // Сохраняет изменения на устройство (По умолчанию это делается при выходе из приложения, в случаях сбоя и экстренного выхода из приложения данные не будут сохранены). *Имейте в виду что вызов данного метода вызывает тормоза, и следует вызывать его  в не игровом процессе*

Пример сохранения монеток:

```
    [SerializeField] private Text _coinsText; // Ссылка на обьект с текстом монет
    private const int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0; // константа с значением по умолчанию, когда ключ ещё не создан (первый запуск игры)
    private const string COINS_AMOUNT_PREFS = "coins_amount"; // константа с ключём (создана для исключения ошибок при наборе ключа в ручную через "кавычки")
    
    if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey(COINS_AMOUNT_PREFS )) // Проверка если ключ имеется
    {
        _coinsText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(COINS_AMOUNT_PREFS).ToString(); // Назначаем тексту значение 
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(COINS_AMOUNT_PREFS , DEFAULT_VALUE); // Создаем ключ с базовым значением
        _coinsText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(COINS_AMOUNT_PREFS).ToString(); // Назначаем тексту значение с ключа который только что создали
    }
```